# Hyper-V Initial Replication over LAN seems capped at 50mbps

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, replication

I've ran the initial replication process over LAN multiple times with these exact two servers.

When I start the initial replication, typically I see my network adapters get floored with sending at like 500-600 mbps, and receiving the same on the replica server.

For reasons unknown to me, and the purpose of my question here, is that for some reason when I started a new initial replication a couple nights ago, the speed which it was transmitting the initial replica was bouncing between 50 and 60 mbps. Is there something I've missed or accidently enabled which is capping this?

Both Hypervisors are running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Thanks for any insight you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer to my question. I moved one of the vhds to an external USB3 hard drive on the replica server, and it was running on the "Quick removal" policy. I thought I had already set it to the "Better Performance" policy when I originally set up the drive, but this was not the case.

So, I:

- Changed to "Better performace"
- Restarted the Server
- Started initial replication

I was suddenly seeing the 400-600 mbps speeds I'm used to.